# Make element with smaller z-index clickable

Tags: css, z-index

I got two elements, one stacked upon the other with z-index. Now my problem is I need to make the element with the lower z-index clickable, too.
How can I achieve this?

Example:

```css
.b {
  margin-top: -50px;
  z-index: 5;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div style="margin-top:100px;">
  <div class="a">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="b">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Give an example of your code.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please provide [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 3):

Just add `pointer-events: none` to your element with higher z-index.

Comment: Thanks, but wouldn't that make the element with higher z-index unclickable? I need to make both elements clickable.

Comment: Have you considered triggering the other click with javascript ?

Comment: Not yet. I wanted to keep things simple but I'm afraid that won't be possible.

Comment: Try this `$(document).on("click", ".b", function(){ $(".a").click(); });`